# Module programming in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, architecture, module

I am basically a Java programmer having programming knowledge of C# and C++. Considering this, please read the following scenario, which I am using to explain my situation.

Imagine I am creating a program. I am a fan of Module programming, so I divided this program into modules. They are:

1. Alarm
2. Security
3. Writer

Now, in Java, I can represent these modules as `packages`, where the `packages` are folders in simple words, outside Java.

Now, if I am going to use C++, how can I do this? How can I arrange these into `packages` or something similar like in Java? And, in my real case, I will be using OpenCV C++ library while using C++/CLI for GUI and some C# modules created as DLLs.

My program will be pretty big and complex, and I don't want to see a mess where all the classes, DLLs and everything else located in same folder without any clear arrangement.

### Update

Image I have another module called "Speak". This module will be C++/CLI because both C# and C++ will be there. How can I arrange this into `packages`?

Comment: @DavidBrown: Thank you a lot for the reply. I made a small update, please be kind enough to answer to that as well.

Answer (score 2):

As far as how you organize your files on the hard drive, it's **entirely** up to you. When you build the system you have to make sure the compiler knows where the files are; unlike Java, the C++ compiler won't hunt around and try to figure out what you might have meant to do.

As far as logical organization, there really isn't enough information here to make solid suggestions. But for a large group of related classes, a namespace might be the right thing.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply. I made a small update, please be kind enough to answer to that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the source and the binary folders in the project settings.
For the scoping, you can use namespaces. Namespaces are very good to prevent name conflicts and giving your program a logical structure, but it does not enforce physical file location.
To enforce physical file structure, you manually create it in file explorer and then add those files to your solution.
But here is a trick: you might want to include a file from an arbitrary folder and you don't want to always give a full address or something like "....\Folder\file.h". Instead, set up your include directory and create includes in there - files without extensions for each header file and inside specify the path to the header file. From the rest of the program, you can simply do #include Myfile (there should be the angular brackets around "MyFile", but stack overflow parser hides them) and you're good to include it from any subfolder.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply. I made a small update, please be kind enough to answer to that as well.

Comment: Are you making the module "Speak" as a library or a standalone console application? In the latter case, you might need to have it in a different project, but in the same solution. If it's a library, I'd still make use of another project, but then you'll need to read about how to "export" dll functions so that they could be accessible from the outside.